# how to insert an array in sqlite?

Tags: go, sqlite

I have struct like:

```
type Foo struct {
  bars []string
}
```

Since sqlite3 doesn't have array data type supported, can we store `[]string` as string and while retrieving return as slice of string? Was trying to implement like below, but getting error because of type mismatch. What need to be done here?

Edit: I have changed the code and look like working

```
type strArray []string

func (strarr StrArray) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if strarr != nil {
        resarr := strings.Join(strarr, "")
        return resarr, nil
    }
    return nil, nil
}
```

Comment: Include your complete error message.

Comment: `strings.Split` is used to split a string into a slice, not to convert a slice into a string. You probably want `Join` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Complementary to `database/sql/driver.Valuer` you need also to implement `database/sql.Scanner` for reading your type from the database.
When you think of how to implement it, it's obvious that in `Valuer` you should `Join` your slice with some delimiter character/string (not occurring in the data of course) to be able to `Split` it back when retrieving.

Assuming that such delimiter would be `;` (my wild guess), the code for reading would look like:

```
func (a *strArray) Scan(value interface{}) error {
  if value == nil {
    return nil  // case when value from the db was NULL
  }
  s, ok := value.(string)
  if !ok {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to cast value to string: %v", value)
  }
  *a = strings.Split(s, ";")
  return nil
}
```

For writing, you'd need to use `strings.Join(strarr, ";")` in `Valuer` implementation.

Other less-trivial implementation would require marshaling your slice and encoding the resulting bytes as string somehow (base32/64? json?). In any case you need to not loose the information what are distinct slice elements when saving them to the database.